# Translate mouse move to camera move in Threejs

Tags: 3d, camera, three.js

I'm trying to implement mouse grabbing of the object and moving it. So I'm translating mouse x and y offset into threejs camera x and z position like that:

```
this.moveCamera = function (x, y) {
    // horizontal movement
    if (x != 0 && y == 0) {
        var move = x / 1000 * camera.position.y
        camera.position.x += move
        camera.position.z += move
    }

    // vertical movement
    if (x == 0 && y != 0) {
        var move = y / 500 * camera.position.y
        camera.position.x += -move
        camera.position.z += +move
    }
}
```

where x is old x mouse position minus new x mouse position (and y the same):

```
if (dragStart) {
    var dragEnd = PickerGame.getPoint(event)
    GameScene.moveCamera(dragStart.x - dragEnd.x, dragStart.y - dragEnd.y)
    dragStart = dragEnd
}
```

Problem is that horizontal and vertical movement is easy but I don't know how to implement diagonal type of movement. What should I do to translate diagonal mouse moves into camera diagonal moves?

This is camera initialization code:

```
cameraY = 24,
initCamera = function (w, h) {
    var viewAngle = 22,
        near = 1,
        far = 1000

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewAngle, w / h, near, far)
    camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'
    camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4
    camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2))
    camera.position.y = cameraY
    camera.scale.addScalar(1)
    scene.add(camera)
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x777777))
}
```

Here is working jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/brbfdLo5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
    radiansX = 2 * Math.PI + Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2)),
    radiansY = 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 4,
    degreesX = radiansX * (180 / Math.PI),
    degreesY = radiansY * (180 / Math.PI),
    initCamera = function (w, h) {
        var viewAngle = 22,
            near = 1,
            far = 1000

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewAngle, w / h, near, far)
        camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'
        camera.rotation.y = radiansY
        camera.rotation.x = radiansX

        console.log(degreesX)
        console.log(degreesY)

        camera.position.y = cameraY
        camera.scale.addScalar(1)
        scene.add(camera)
        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x777777))
    }
```

and this

```
this.moveCamera = function (x, y) {
    x = -x
    y = -y * 2

    var angleX = degreesX,
        angleY = degreesY


    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(x, 0, y),
        mRx = new THREE.Matrix3(),
        mRy = new THREE.Matrix3(),
        cosX = Math.cos(angleX),
        sinX = Math.sin(angleX),
        cosY = Math.cos(angleY),
        sinY = Math.sin(angleY)

    mRx.set(
        1, 0, 0,
        0, cosX, -sinX,
        0, sinX, cosX
    )

    mRy.set(
        cosY, 0, sinY,
        0, 1, 0,
        -sinY, 0, cosY
    )

    vector.applyMatrix3(mRx)
    vector.applyMatrix3(mRy)

    camera.position.x -= vector.x * camera.position.y / 1000
    camera.position.z += vector.z * camera.position.y / 1000
}
```

made it work

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. I've removed the `* camera.position.y` because that should end up making the camera move faster as you get higher in the scene and then move in the opposite direction of what you'd expect when you hit negative values lower in the scene.

```
this.moveCamera = function (x, y) {
    var xmove = x / 32;// * camera.position.y
    var ymove = y / 32;// * camera.position.y

    camera.position.x += xmove;
    camera.position.y -= ymove;
}
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/elindie/4xu49sLv/4/

Comment: What is 'xMove' and 'zMove'? What do you need 'move' for?

Comment: I have changed firs move to xMove and second move to zMove and it is not working as it should: https://jsfiddle.net/4xu49sLv/2/

Comment: I've updated my answer and edited your fiddle, hope that helps

Comment: Not really. Y camera position defines the high at which camera is positioned. And as you can see in you jsfiddle camera is not following mouse moves. To change camera position over object you have to change x and z. Look at my jsfiddle in my question (I edited it).

Comment: In your jsfiddle when you move mouse to the right you are zooming out and object is getting smaller.

Comment: Are you trying to get RTS camera like movement then? Sort of a three quarters view?

Comment: Look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brbfdLo5/3/ and try to move keyboard arrows. This is the type of camera movement I need but with mouse. Problem is only with diagonal moves.

Comment: If you can provide a real world example, I'll happily take another look.

Comment: Real world example: http://warsoftheheroes.eu/en/login 
You can register or use this login: anonim, password: 123456